# using for loop(.each) in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have this function notify() with three parameters, user id(number), message, and link. On the website that I am working on, there are users that are invited to a party by a party host, and I wanna use this notify function to notify only those users that are invited. Every user has their own name and id (in numbers). But since the user id is a number, how do I use for loop (.each) to notify those users that are invited? For instance, there are 7 users (user 1-7), but only the users 1,3,5 are invited so I want to notify only 1,3, and 5.

P.S. This is what I have so far, I am so new to JQuery so please help!

```
if ($('#create-party-form').length) { //not sure if it's even right..
        $('#submit-invitation-btn').on('click', function() {
            $('').each(function() { //this is where I am stuck

            })
            notify( ,message, link); //first one should be id# of users that are invited..
        });
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Trying to accomplish these things with no understanding of how the code works, is like trying to build a house without the understanding of construction code. You have to crawl before you can walk. You have to walk before you can run. Learn to crawl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you store the users, but assuming you have an array of user ids who are invited.

```js
const invited = [1, 3, 5];
invited.forEach(id => notify(id, message, link);
```

This is also not using any jQuery, as you can see it is really simple.

Or perhaps you store the users like this?

```js
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Michael',
  invited: true
}
```

In that case, you can use filter:

```
users
  .filter(user => user.invited)
  .forEach(user => notify(user.id, message, link)
);
```